# Prove that $R$ does not have an identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be the collection of sequences $(a_1,a_2,...)$ of integers $a_1$, $a_2$,..., **where all but finitely many of the $a_i$ are $0$**.

$1$.Prove that $R$ is a ring under componentwise addition and multiplication

$2.$ Prove that $R$ does not have an identity

**My attempt** : I can easily show the properties  of inverse ,associative and distributive  in $R$

I have no any problem with question $1$.

My doubt in question $2$ that $R$ does not have identity

I think $R$  have identity take  $e= (0,0,0,..0,1,1,1..)$

Note :**where all but finitely many of the $a_i$ are $0$** mean that $R$ have infinitely many $0$

Comment: Note that "all but finitely many of the $a_i$'s are $0$" implies that "infinitely many of the $a_i$'s are zero", but not conversely. For example $(1 , 0 , 1 , 0 ,  \ldots )$ has infinitely many entries which are zero, but it is not an element of $R$, since it also has infinitely many entries which are nonzero.

Comment: okss ..thanks for correction @NateGallup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that $R$ admits an identity element $1 \in R.$ Then we should have that $e_i \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot e_i = e_i$ for all $1 \leq i,$ where $e_i \in R$ is the element with $1$ on position $i$ and $0$ on all the others. Write $1 = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, \dots) \in R.$ By the definition of $R$, there is $M \geq 1$ such that $x_j = 0$ for all $j \geq M.$ But then $e_M \cdot 1 = (0, 0, \dots, 0, \dots) \neq e_M,$ hence a contradiction. Thus, $R$ is not a unital ring.

Comment: I think  you have  done some typo mistake $e_m \cdot 1 = (0, 0, \dots, 0, \dots) \neq e_M,$ it should be $e_M \cdot 1 = (0, 0, \dots, 0, \dots) \neq e_M,$.

Comment: yes, it is obviously $e_M,$ I don’t think anybody questioned that

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that an identity element of $R$ has to belong to $R$. Which is not the case of $e= (0,0,0,..0,1,1,1..)$ that only has a finite number of zeros.